# Python/Scrapy - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, scrapy

Help! When doing anything with scrapy i get the following error

```
C:\Users\danie>scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 7, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_newtls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\tls.py", line 63, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py", line 157, in <module>
    verifyHostname, VerificationError = _selectVerifyImplementation()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_sslverify.py", line 140, in _selectVerifyImplementation
    from service_identity import VerificationError
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\service_identity\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cryptography, pyopenssl
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\service_identity\cryptography.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from asn1crypto.keys import PublicKeyInfo
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\keys.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ._elliptic_curve import (
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_elliptic_curve.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._int import inverse_mod
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_int.py", line 56, in <module>
    from ._perf._big_num_ctypes import libcrypto
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_perf\_big_num_ctypes.py", line 31, in <module>
    libcrypto_path = find_library('crypto')
  File "c:\python27\lib\ctypes\util.py", line 53, in find_library
    fname = os.path.join(directory, name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The last thing i did was trying to execute a spider with slenium (scrapy crawl xy) that wasnt started with "scrapy startproject XY" . Since then i can´t do anything with scrapy, and im always getting this error. I tried restarting my computer and un/reinstalling scrapy, but the error persists.

Im using Windows 10, scrapy version 1.4.0

Comment: Is your copy-paste verbatim? It looks like it could be a problem with a non-ascii character in the user path

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that i had added something in PATH that didnt have ascii characters. Problem solved (Thanks @AlastairMcCormack )